# Vertical repeating pattern

Tags: print-quality

I've got these strange vertical grooves on my print. They are, at some locations well feelable and at some locations they are completely gone. The printer is an Ender 5 Plus or based on it at least. I use a MicroSwiss Dual Gear Bowden extruder instead of the stock one. Are they from the extruder or from the belts? Or something completely different?

[image]

Comment: If they're positionally aligned across layers like this, the chance of them being extrusion related is essentially zero. Most likely either positioning system related (belt/motor stuff) or actually present in the STL file.

Answer (score 0):

Are the patterns only visible on opposite sides of the print by any chance? If it is, the problem can be isolated to a specific axis (only X or Y axis in this case)

You could start with the basic checks like belt tension or something else that came loose. maybe even worn out belts.

I've had some (for me at least) unexpected patterns on what should be smooth curves that turned out to be a setting in the export as mesh function in Fusion360. The resolution was set too low so the [STL triangles](https://all3dp.com/1/stl-file-format-3d-printing/) became visible.

I doubt this last option is the problem in your case because the pattern should be visible all along the part so as mentioned before I would start with checking your X and Y axis

Comment: I also thought of the STL resolution first and increased the resolution, but that didn't help. So I guess it's down the age-old question, what's the correct belt tension.

Comment: @MarcoRebsamen: Not just belt tension. Also motor current, intrinsic properties of the motors, whether you have belt teeth running on smooth idlers anywhere (bad bad BAD!!), etc.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I also thought of the idlers. At the front they are actually flat. But I'm having a hard time finding different ones that fit and are not only available on amazon.